# Subscribing to a non-existing topic

Tags: ros, publisher, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible for a node to subscribe to a topic which doesn't exist yet? This would be useful if the node publishing on this topic has to be started after the listener.

To put this into context, I have three nodes (A, B, C) and two topics (T1 and T2). Node A publishes on T1. Node B subscribes to T1 and publishes on T2. Finally, Node C only subscribes on T2.

As I have experienced, I must run node A before node B as B will not be able to subscribe on T1 because it doesn't exist until some node publishes on it. The same happens for B and C and therefore I must run the nodes in the proper order (A then B then C). This is not a problem in my case, but if there was a third topic (T3) on which C would publish and A would listen, that would create a problem.

There must be a cleaner way to solve this problem but I haven't found one in ROS documentation yet. Any idea?

Thanks!

---

Update: reinitializing roscore solved the problem. I'm not sure what was the cause of the problem, though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38912/subscribing-to-a-non-existing-topic/) by [nlauzier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2534/nlauzier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nlauzier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2534/nlauzier/) on 2012-07-16**:
By the way, I am using rospy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes you can subscribe to an unpublished topic but you may not retrieve any data in your callback till topic is published

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nlauzier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2534/nlauzier/) on 2012-07-16**:
You are right, if I run "rostopic list -v", I can see that the topic exists and that it has one subscriber. However, when I run the node publishing on that topic, the callback function of the listener is never called.

**Comment by [nlauzier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2534/nlauzier/) on 2012-07-16**:
And if I run the same listener node twice (one before and one after the publisher is run), only the one run after the publisher will get its callback function called.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
In that case something is wrong. Verify that both nodes are running and connected. Do they have different names?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-16**:
Running the *same* node twice deletes the first one from the ROS graph, so that behavior is correct and expected.

**Comment by [nlauzier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2534/nlauzier/) on 2012-07-16**:
ok, now I'm not sure why but restarting roscore solved my problem. Is it possible that modifying my code or node/topic names needs a reinitialisation of roscore?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
It's possible that you left a connection open, then restarted roscore (which doesn't know about the old node still running) and then reconnected? Also refer to @joq's comment.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
If you need multiple nodes, use different names from launch or cmd line or make the names Anonymous.